# Why is the range of covariance infinity?

Tags: probability, random-variables, covariance

I don't understand why the range of covariance is $+\infty,-\infty$

$$\operatorname{Cov} (X,Y)= \Bbb E\left[(X-\mu_x)(Y-\mu_y)\right] .$$

Can explain why this is true?

All I can think of is if one of the random variables can take on large enough values, then could that lead to an expected value at $\infty$?

Comment: If $X$ has a finite mean and infinite variance then $Cov(X,X)=+\infty$ and  $Cov(X,-X)=-\infty$.  A Pareto distribution with $1 \lt \alpha \le 2$ would do

Comment: To stay with random variables with finite variance, choose your favorite square integrable random variable $X$ with unit variance and note that $\mathrm{Cov}(aX,aX)=a^2$ and $\mathrm{Cov}(aX,-aX)=-a^2$ for every $a$. Thus every real number is a covariance. But, technically speaking, recall that the covariance is only defined for square integrable random variables hence it is never infinite.